# NSString value disappear 0x00000000

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have @property:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *response;
```

In ViewDidLoad I add some value:

```
response = @"test";
```

In another function prepareForSegue I try to send value of this variable to next view but 
value is disappear and I see

```
(NSString *) response = 0x000000010a8a9e00
```

in response value but must be "test", and same problem with some other variables. What is this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid doing this whenever possible as it can cause bugs like the one you're having:

```
response = @"test";
```

Instead, always do:

```
self.response = @"test";
```